# Custom Alert view for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to implement my own alert view for an iphone app. The app supports all orientations and also often shows both a tabbar and navbar. Currently, I add my custom alert view as a subview of the active view controller - this works well as it supports a transparent overlay and rotation is supported. However, the tabbar and navbar are not covered by the alert view's overlay. I have discarded adding the alert to the keywindow as this does not support rotation readily and because of other issues with using the keywindow. Any suggestions on how to implement a custom alert with a transparent overlay that would also cover any nav and/or tab bar and also support rotation please?

Comment: UIAlertViews add themselves to the key window - what's wrong with it? You can always check for the orientation using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`...

Comment: @H2CO2 There are 2 issues with that approach: 1. Manual rotation support when rotation occurs during display of the alert 2. The app keywindow is swapped out by iOS at irregular intervals causing occasional crashes when then calling removeFromSuperview on the alert

Comment: Having used the key window, I fully agree that this is the wrong way to go. Instead, use the top view of the app: `keywindow.rootViewController.view`. To handle rotation, add an observer on the `bounds` property of the top view. Works like a charm.